# How to get value from useState inside the function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build Hanging man game and want to get value from useState inside the checkMatchLetter function, but not sure if that is possible and what I did wrong....

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchButton } from '../actions';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'babel-polyfill';

const App = () => {
    const [word, setWord] = useState([]);
    const [underscore, setUnderscore] = useState([]);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const runEffect = async () => {
            const result = await axios('src/api/api.js');
            setData(result.data)
        }
        runEffect();
    }, []);

    const randomWord = () => {
        const chosenWord = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
        replaceLetter(chosenWord.word);
    }

    const replaceLetter = (string) => {
      
        let getString = string; // here it shows a valid string.
        setWord(getString);
        let stringToUnderScore = getString.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '_');
        setUnderscore(stringToUnderScore);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkLetter = (event) => {
            if(event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
                checkMatchLetter(word, String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase());
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);
        }
    }, []);

    const checkMatchLetter = (keyButton) => {
        console.log(keyButton);
        let wordLength = word.length;
        console.log(wordLength); // here it outputs '0'
        /// here I want word of useState here....
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{word}</p>
            <p>{underscore}</p>
            <button onClick={randomWord}></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

The reason why I want to obtain that value inside this function is so I can compare the clicked keybutton (a-z) to the current chosenword. And if there is something wrong with other functions, please feel free to share your feedback here below as well.

Comment: From the code you provide, `word` is in scope. Have you tried adding some code to checkMatchLetter which interacts with `word`?

Comment: Yes, but the word was still undefined...which is very weird to me.

Comment: So, you initialize `word` to an empty array. And in the code you provided there's nowhere where you call `setWord`, so it should remain an empty array. If you're getting `undefined`, maybe the code you had was trying to access an index of the array which doesn't exist? If you still have the code you tried in checkMatchLetter, please share it with us.

Comment: Even when I call **setWord** it still would not output anything....

Comment: Why do you have useeffect twice ?

Comment: @Afsanefda that's one of the benefits that hooks gave us: being able to group related code together instead of having to put it all in one place. Fetching data and adding key listeners are completely unrelated effects.

Comment: @Freshdeveloper unfortunately, without knowing what code you wrote, i'm left just guessing what the issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a variable defined inside the component render function in a `useEffect` effect and that variable is missing in the hook's deps. Always include the deps you need (I highly recommend the lint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`). When you add `checkMatchLetter` to deps you'll always have the newest instance of the function inside your effect instead of always using the old version from the first render like you do now.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const checkLetter = (event) => {
        if(event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
            checkMatchLetter(word, String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase());
        }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);
    }
}, [checkMatchLetter, word]);
```

This change will make the effect run on every render. To rectify that, you can memoise your callbacks. However, that's a new can of worms.